# Variable does not exist in batch query

Tags: apex, batch

I'm writing a batch class that takes in a string, does the query and then passes the results to a method to process. I want to use the string in the query, but when I add it in I get the error:

> Variable does not exist: versionFY

I set it above the string and in the load method but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Example:

```
global class NPD_Batch_BudgetToolLoad implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
private String versionId;   
private String versionFY;
private Map<String, Id> pStructureMap;   
private Map<String, Id> practiceMap;

private static final String QUERY = 
    'SELECT Id,' +  
    .....           
    'FROM   Revenue_Pipeline__c ' +
    'WHERE  Year__c = ' + versionFY;

public NPD_Batch_BudgetToolLoad(Map<String, Id> pStructureMap, Map<String, Id> practiceMap, String versionId, String versionFY) 
{
    this.versionId = versionId;
    this.versionFY = versionFY;
    this.pStructureMap = pStructureMap;
    this.practiceMap = practiceMap;
}       

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
{
    return Database.getQueryLocator(QUERY);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Revenue_Pipeline__c> scope)  
{
    //NPD_BudgetingDataLoad.createProjectedRevenue(scope, versionId, pStructureMap, practiceMap);   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to merge in a variable, the proper approach would be:

```
String soql = '... WHERE Field__c = :mergeVariableName';
//                                  ^ you are missing the bind character
//                                    you also want the name of the variable, not its value
```

You could alternatively merge in the literal string instead of binding, but then you need to wrap it in escaped single quotes:

```
String soql = '... WHERE Field__c = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(myVariable) + '\'';
```

Don't neglect escaping, as doing so would open up an injection vulnerability.