# Query with parameter in Batch using Iterable

Tags: apex

I want to make a query that field `Source = 'SPS'`,
I have a batch class that is using `Iterable`, but I always get the error: `variable does not exist: sourceVal`.

How do I make it work?
This is my code:

```
global class UT_MDM_Email_MonthlyReport_SPS implements Database.Batchable<AggregateResult> {
    // The batch job starts
    global Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        String sourceVal = 'SPS';
        System.debug('sourceVal :' + sourceVal);
        String query = 'SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name plant FROM Contact WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Is_Drop__c = FALSE AND Source__c=:sourceVal GROUP BY Owner.UserRole.Name';
        return new AggregateResultIterable(query);
    }

    // The batch job executes and operates on one batch of records
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope){
        for(sObject sObj : scope) {
            AggregateResult ar = (AggregateResult)sObj;
            System.debug('>>>> plant : ' + ar.get('plant'));
        }
    }
}
```

AggregateResultIterator Class:

```
global class AggregateResultIterator Implements Iterator<AggregateResult>{

    AggregateResult [] results {get;set;}
    // tracks which result item is returned
    Integer index {get; set;}

    global AggregateResultIterator(String query) {
        index = 0;
        results = Database.query(query);
    }

    global boolean hasNext(){
        return results != null && !results.isEmpty() && index < results.size();
    }

    global AggregateResult next(){
        return results[index++];
    }
}
```

AggregateResultIterable Class:

```
global class AggregateResultIterable implements Iterable<AggregateResult>{
    private String query;

    global AggregateResultIterable(String soql){
        query = soql;
    }

    global Iterator<AggregateResult> Iterator(){
        return new AggregateResultIterator(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable does not exist in batch query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201170/variable-does-not-exist-in-batch-query)

Comment: You can type it explicitely as `Source__c = \'' + sourceVal + '\' GROUP BY`. Not an answer, just a workaround to make it work, I'm also curious why you cannot use bind variable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Database.query` can only see variables in the current *scope*. When you pass the query string here:

```
    return new AggregateResultIterable(query);
```

That variable is no longer in scope. You'll want to read more about scope in the [Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm) documentation.

Since there's only a maximum of 2,000 rows that you can return in an aggregate result query, you may as well just pass in the query directly:

```
public class AggregateResultIterator Implements Iterator<AggregateResult> {
    AggregateResult [] results;
    public AggregateResultIterator(AggregateResult[] results) {
        this.results = results.clone();
    }
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return !results.isEmpty();
    }
    public AggregateResult next(){
        return results.remove(0);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class AggregateResultIterable implements Iterable<AggregateResult>{
    AggregateResult[] results;
    public AggregateResultIterable(AggregateResult[] results){
        this.results = results;
    }
    public Iterator<AggregateResult> iterator(){
        return new AggregateResultIterator(results);
    }
}
```

---

```
return new AggregateResultIterable([
  SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name plant FROM Contact WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Is_Drop__c = FALSE AND Source__c=:sourceVal GROUP BY Owner.UserRole.Name
]);
```

---

All that said, there's no reason to do this. A `List<AggregateResult>` already implements `Iterable<AggregateResult>`, so you can return it directly:

```
public AggregateResult[] start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    String sourceVal = 'SPS';
    System.debug('sourceVal :' + sourceVal);
    return [
      SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name plant 
      FROM Contact 
      WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Is_Drop__c = FALSE AND Source__c=:sourceVal 
      GROUP BY Owner.UserRole.Name
    ];
}
```

---

One final note: you can implement interfaces using public, rather than global, and this is recommended unless you intend for a class outside of your package scope running this batchable class, which is usually never for unpackaged batchable classes, and rarely for ISV packages.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code, and works perfectly

```
String query = 'SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name plant FROM Contact WHERE Email_Support__c != NULL AND Is_Drop__c = FALSE AND Source__c=\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(sourceVal)+'\'GROUP BY Owner.UserRole.Name';
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine, but please, do not close the question, because bind variable as single String should also work just fine, and the question is, why it IS NOT)

Comment: I found this page that explained it, https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093fyIAA&_ga=2.259974026.1040666098.1671368756-803331378.1667205070

Comment: No it doesn't, you can run this code sample and see that it works just fine with bind variables and aggregate result: `String sourceVal = 'Outbound'; System.debug('sourceVal: ' + sourceVal); String query = 'SELECT Owner.UserRole.Name plant FROM Lead WHERE LeadSource = :sourceVal AND CreatedDate = TODAY GROUP BY Owner.UserRole.Name'; List<AggregateResult> res = Database.query(query); System.debug(res);` . And in your link there is also and answer from `vbs` that confirms it. It doesn't explain, why it doesn't work in your case.